# What (if any) is the maximum possible number of pieces ina Rubik's cube?

Tags: rubiks-cube

What (if any) is the maximum possible number of pieces in a Rubik's cube---27? 64? 125? 216? 343?...or does the maximum end with 125?

Comment: What do you mean by "piece"? And what sorts of puzzles do you mean by [Rubik's cube](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/617yg6Qx5SL._SX300_.jpg)?

Comment: http://superliminal.com/cube/cube.htm

Answer (score 4):

There's no maximum.

[This article](http://www.ign.com/articles/2015/01/12/17x17x17-rubiks-cube-the-worlds-largest-solved-in-75-hours) discusses a 17x17x17 cube, and the technique used to make it could easily be extended.

(Also, keep in mind that the Rubik's Cube generally doesn't have any inside cubies. The standard cube has only 26 actual cubies, and most of them are deformed on the inside to make the mechanism work.